# How to add placeholder to all Drupal 7 text forms in node page?

Tags: forms

I'm trying to add the placeholders from field description to all Drupal 7 text forms only in node page using Drupal API

I've created a module that overrides hook_form_alter

```
  <?php
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form'] == TRUE) {       
        foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == "textfield") {
            $form['type'][$value]['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $form['#description']; 
            unset($form['#description']);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

?>

How to do it using Drupal Api without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

I take it by wanting a Placeholder that the text is going to be removed by javaScript when the use enters text ?

If so, there are a couple of modules for that, for example :
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_placeholder

This will give you an extra setting in the field setting form so you wont have to use your description, allowing it to be used for the description.

Comment: I have found this module when looking for a solution before. But I need custom module. Thanks

Comment: sure thing, but the module is pretty small and does do it in the drupal-way, by hooking into Field API to give you more options. But if you want to keep code down you can do it all in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

For title Description use [Title field UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_field_ui) Module.

You can try

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') { // as your condition
            drupal_add_js(
              "(function ($) {
                Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
                    attach: function (context, settings) {
                        $('input[type=text]').each(function(index){
                            desc = $(this).parent().find('.description').html();
                            $(this).attr( 'placeholder', desc );  $(this).parent().find('.description').css('display','none');// hide description
                        });
                    }
                };
            })(jQuery);", array(
              'type' => 'inline',
              'scope' => 'header',
              'weight' => 5,
              )
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works, except for the Title field. How do it for Title and for all node page, and even hide a field Description?

Comment: And only for text field

Comment: Don't Ask question in comment. Edit own question and ask their.

Comment: Im edit question, pls help correct code

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered editing the content type and providing a default value for the field with your placeholder text.

If you need to make the default text disappear when the user clicks on the field, you can use jQuery to detect focus on the field and remove the text. If the user doesn't add new text, it can be returned when focus is off the field, otherwise the new text stays.

Comment: I need to have the text was taken from the field description

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but should be near the mark:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form'] == TRUE) {   
    _MYMODULE_apply_placeholder($form);
  }
}

function _MYMODULE_apply_placeholder(&$element) {
  if (!empty($element['#description']) && $element['#type'] == 'textfield') {
    $element['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $element['#description'];
    unset($element['#description']);
  }

  foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
    _MYMODULE_apply_placeholder($element[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: #type

Comment: I'm update question